# Error running .class files

Tags: java, class, url, io

I wonder why the Game.class wont start. Here's he problem I got:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Game (wrong name: game/Game)`

  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)


 Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with packaging. Can you post the .java file with class definition and the structure of your jar?

Comment: what? I dont have the game.java i just have game.class and i do not run it throught a jar, i just run it.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means that `Game.class` alone is not enough to run this class. You need to add everything it depends on to classpath.

Comment: ahhh thank you gigadot, but does it mean i should put this class file as well as the other class files it needs in a jar file to be able to run them all at same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get similar error if you do mething like this:

```
package game;

class Game 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

without putting the compiled class file in a sub-folder called game and run it like java Game. So your Game class is in a package called game.

Comment: so i put the required class file inside the class file and then run it. the only thing is that when i decompile the game.class file i found a folder named game :).

Comment: @CarlPersson: Of course, it is supposed to be put in that folder to reflect the package hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your packaging structure and ensure that your class file is inside the package folder . Compile and Happy Execution ....